# Expanding DIV does not hide in IE 11

Tags: jquery, css

This fiddle expands the paragraph after the 'i', and then you can hide/truncate it again with 'Hide':

https://jsfiddle.net/my8jpn01/45/

Works in Chrome/Firefox, **does not work in IE 11**. Any thoughts why IE11 doesn't expand it? Is it these attributes in CSS, or something in jQuery?

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Strategy: switch styles (from '.inlinehelpdetail' to '.inlinehelpdetail.expanded') to hide/show the DIV. The jQuery does the addClass/removeClass, that's all there is to this current fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop), `initial` isn't a valid value for `white-space`. The value you're looking for is `white-space: normal`, which is supported by all browsers.

EDIT: `initial` might be a valid global value, but it doesn't have an explicit meaning when it comes to `white-space` according to the spec, thus the difference in behavior (and IE acting correctly, IMHO :-)).

Comment: No problem. Chrome's dev tools suggests `initial` as a valid value in a few spots where it might not always work, which has nailed me a few times.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close:

`.helpwithdetail.expanded {
    white-space: initial;
    width: 550px;
    overflow: visible;
}`

Comment: this works, thanks. Only issue is, it overflows on the same line: https://jsfiddle.net/my8jpn01/49/ . AJM's solution of 'white-space: normal' however kept it multi-line as before while fixing the IE11 issue. Thanks again